# Material UI style with Next.js will break

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I tried to move a project from plain React to Next.js and I just can't make it work.
I even tried to just copy the files to another working next.js project and it's the same.

It seems that it is broken on production every time but just sometimes in dev (broken, but different from production).

When I refresh the page it will break almost every time.

The footer component is broken almost 90% of the time.

If I navigate with the Link component it works fine almost every time (except the footer) but if I refresh or use Router it will break.

I imported all the styles components (makeStyles, createStyles, Theme) from "@material-ui/core/styles" and then I tried with "@material-ui/core" and still not working.

Production build images:
[image: Production build img]
[image: Production build2 img]

Dev broken images
[image: Dev broken img]
[image: Dev working img]

Code:

[This is the _document file from material documentation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js)

[The _app file](https://github.com/Dumnezeu1/auto-shop/blob/main/pages/_app.tsx)

The same files (_document and _app) are used in another project and that project works.

[Github repo](https://github.com/Dumnezeu1/auto-shop)

Answer (score 0):

I just added in my _document file

```
const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();

const css = sheets.toString();
```

and in return in the `<Head> ... </Head>` tag I added

```
<style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
```

and now it seems like it works.

Comment: this isn't working